# Importing Excel records on Filemaker Server using PSoS

Tags: excel, import, filemaker

New to FileMaker server and have been trying to roll it out for my own company but running into a problem I can't seem to solve or find the right answers to online.

I am saving an excel file called **import.xlsx** in **/Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Documents/** and using a variable filepath to point to the file this script does not work when used in PSoS step. However if I specify the file locally whilst using FMP, and using only the script "Import Test" the import works fine.

Is it a problem with the variable filepath I have set? Or have I missed something out? I have included the two scripts that I wrote to try and make the import happen via PSoS. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!! - Yong

**Script to Trigger PSoS "Import PSoS Button"**

```
Commit Records/Request
Perform Script on Server[ "Import Test" ]
```

**Script to Import Records from Excel "Import Test"**

```
Go to Layout [ "Test" (Test) ]
Set Variable [ $filepath ; Value: "filemac:" & Get(DocumentsPath) & "import.xlsx" ]
Import Records [ With dialog: Off ; Source: "$filepath"; Worksheet: "" ; Add; Mac Roman ]
```

UPDATE:
I have tried using a .csv file in the place of the .xlsx file and the script works perfectly. Still not sure why a .xlsx file doesn't work as it is stated that FileMaker server 15 supports .xlsx import records script step (http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/12067/~/import%2Fexport-script-steps-with-filemaker-server-scheduled-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to prepend the path with "filemac:" since the function gets the correct path. Can you try it without and see if that does it?

Comment: Hi SoliantMike! I tried it and nothing happens, I've set error capture on and using Get(LastError), with or without "filemac:" the error code is 0, but if I change the filename to something that doesn't exist (import123.xlsx), it shows the error 100, hence it is reaching the file but it's not importing anything. Very puzzling. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: May be need to check field mapping in import dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update that I figured out what is wrong after all these time. Filemaker Server does support server side imports with .xlsx, what was going wrong was the file rights that is inside the /Library/FileMaker Server/Data/Documents/ folder. To have server side imports to work, you have to make sure that for the specific file .csv or .xlsx, you have to make sure that either (fmsadmin) or (fmserver User) has read rights to that file. Add it if it doesn't.

Can't believe it has taken me that long to figure that out. Not sure why this isn't documented anywhere. Hope it helps whoever else is facing this problem, cheers!

YS